# need help in WHERE clause with PHP update into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, manual

I'm getting errors when I tried to update into database. The error said:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE company_id='2'' at line 6

What does line 6 relate to and how to solve that?

```
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>

<?php 
// Parse the form data and update company information to the system
if (isset($_POST['company_name'])) {

    $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);
    $company_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_name']);
    $company_url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_url']);
    $company_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_username']);
    $company_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_password']);
    
    // See if that company name is an identical match to another company in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE company SET
    company_name='$company_name', 
    company_url='$company_url', 
    company_username='$company_username',
    company_password='$company_password',
    WHERE company_id='$pid'") or die(mysql_error());  
    
    header("location: company.php"); 
    
    
    exit();
}
?>


<?php 
// Gather these companies full information for inserting automatically into the edit form below on page
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE company_id='$targetID' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $company_id = $row["company_id"];
             $company_name = $row["company_name"];
             $company_url = $row["company_url"];
             $company_username = $row["company_username"];
             $company_password = $row["company_password"];
    
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry dude that doesn't exist.";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Try PDO or MySQLi .

Comment: This question can be resolved by fixing a typographical error. Since it showcases some woefully poor security practices _and_ the three answer authors didn't think to mention them, I will try to close this.

Answer (score 2):

Take that comma out after `company_password='$company_password'`

Answer (score 0):

There is extra comma before `WHERE` which is an error.
So, remove it.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE company SET
    company_name='$company_name', 
    company_url='$company_url', 
    company_username='$company_username',
    company_password='$company_password'   // REMOVE COMMA FROM HERE
    WHERE company_id='$pid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your right is relate to comma. things have solved.

Comment: If this is your solution, can you mark my answer as solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have put comma (,) before where clause.

```
company_password='$company_password'

**,**
WHERE company_id='$pid'"
```